# Updating STF's database for mobile devices

Tags: android, mobile, device

Fellow Developers,

How are you? I'm struggling with updating STF (for Ubuntu), the Android Farm app that allows for multiple device using and emulation via browser. The thing is that I need to update its database since it's not recongicing most of the devices we use to carry out QA testings in our company.

Has anyone faced this issue before? Do you work with STF?

Thank you in advance!

Marco

PS: I've tried to whitelist the devices by following this tutorial but had no success at all: https://github.com/apkudo/adbusbini

Answer (score 0):

STF uses another npm package called stf-device-db

https://github.com/openstf/stf-device-db/tree/master/data

You will have to make changes here and rebuild stf with your new version.

In your npm module directory, there is a subfolder for node_modules. In there you will find stf-device-db. Maybe try making the changes in there?